# User validation on Custom Button

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I have a custom button on the Product object that I only want to run if the current logged in user is either the record owner, a specific user id, or a sys admin profile. How would I do that? Below is my current code

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js")}

var r = new sforce.SObject("Product2");

r.id = "{!Product2.Id}";

r.Convert_to_Service_Catalogue__c = true;

result = sforce.connection.update([r]);

window.location.reload();

if ( result[0].getBoolean( "success" ) ) {

    location.reload( true ); // refresh page

} else {

    var errors = result[0].errors;
    var errorMessages = "The Lifecycle Status must be Beta, and the following fields must be populated; Name, Unique ID, Jisc Directorate, Include in Dashboard, Service/Project Owner or else this record won't be converted to a Service Catalogue record";

    for ( var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++ ) {
        errorMessages += errors[i].message + '\n';
    }

    alert( errorMessages ); // display all validation errors

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As always with things like this, if you can find a way to do this using Page Layouts then even better. That would at least work for System Admins, but you'll  probably hit a wall with allowing specific users to perform this action.

I think you may find this easiest if you use Apex and process things from there.

For example, if you have a class called `ProductAction` and a method called `convertToService`, the buttons JavaScript would look like this:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")}

var result = sforce.apex.execute("ProductAction","convertToService",{product:"{!Product.Id}"});
window.location.href = '/'+result[0].Id+'/e';
```

This will just pass in to the method the product Id assigned to the variable `product`. The class would look like this:

```
global class ProductAction {
    WebService static String convertToService(Id product) {
        String result; // Return a string telling us if this worked or not
        Id currentProfile = UserInfo.getProfileId(); // Get the current user profile Id
        Id currentUser = UserInfo.getUserId(); // Get the current user Id

        Set<Id> allowedProfiles = new Set<Id>(); // Create a new set to store profile Ids
        for (Profile p : [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator']) { // Get the System Administrator profile
            allowedProfiles.add(p) // Add it to the Set
        }

        Set<Id> allowedUsers = new Set<Id>();   // Create a new set to stor User Ids
        for (User u : [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE [...]]) { // Query whatever it is that makes the User allowed to do this
            allowedUsers.add(u) // Add them to the set
        }

        Product prod = [SELECT Convert_to_Service_Catalogue__c, Owner.Id FROM Product WHERE Id = :product]; // Get the product

        if ( // If...
            (currentUser == product.Owner.Id) || // They own it
            (allowedProfiles.contains(currentProfile)) || // They're a system admin
            (allowedUsers.contains(currentUser)) // They're a specific user
        ) {
            // Do stuff!
            prod.Convert_to_Service_Catalogue__c = true;

            UPDATE prod;

            result = 'Success!';
        }
        else { // Otherwis...
            // Do nothing
            reuslt = 'Go away!';
        }

        // Return a message
        return result;
    }
}
```

I've quickly put this together which (might) actually solve your problem entirely, but you may want to make it a bit tidier.

Comment: That was really helpful, as in the way you've written it, but it's not working. I've posted another question. would you know the answer? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148609/custom-button-failing-no-such-parameter-product2-defined-for-the-operation-pl